# issue when trying to use extendType in prisma nexusjs

Tags: typescript, nexus-prisma

I tried using `extendtype` in my project because all my files are not in a single folder, so for me to able to interact with them all I use extendType. But in the long run, i encounter an error that I can't fix at the moment.

Here is the error:

```
error:Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

[here is my data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5uvI.png)

and after implementing it to my post file i created an error pop-out

[Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruYyt.png)

Comment: You appear to be extending `Query` in which case you should be giving all your fields resolvers. I'm not sure i understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for trying out Nexus..
it appears that you're having multiple Queries hence you're extending "Query", it seems that it's a VScode problem not reading the newly generated types on time or you're not getting something right, so. try this

- Reload your workspace
- Try to change `t.nonNull.int("id")` to `t.int("id")` if the problem goes away then you're in luck
  but then since you're not writing the model, you need to do something like this

```js
//... your nexus definition before here
       t.list.field("posts", {
            type: "Post",
            args:{
              postId: intArg()
            }
            resolve(parent, { postId }, ctx) {
                return ctx.prisma.post.findMany()
            }
        })
```

always use `t.nonNull` for your nexus models not for queries unless when supplying them in arguments

Secondly, what version  of `nexus` are you using? `t.nonNull` was introduced recently and might have contributed to the culprit, but your Prisma model is just fine